# how to style top parent element using jquery

Tags: jquery

i want style top parent and it should be dynamic. i just want style top parent. we can add more parent div but style should reflect on to div. is that possible with jquery.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('.text').parent().css('background-color','red')
})

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <div>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="text">hiiii</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: What is YOUR definition of `top parent`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "top parent," you may want the `parents` function with the selector `"div"`:

```
$(function(){
    $('.text').parents("div").last().css('background-color','red');
});
```

Note that this will only work as expected if `$('.text')` only matches one element. If it matches more than one, you'll need a loop, e.g.:

```
$(function(){
    $('.text').each(function() {
        $(this).parents("div").last().css('background-color','red');
    });
});
```

...which sets the "top parent" of each matching `.text` to red.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like below:

```
$('.text').parents('div:last').css('background-color','red')​;
```

`.parents()` returns the ancestors in order form inner to outer, so you could plus `:last` selector to get the outermost parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the highest level element from the current selected one. You can use `.parents()` to get all of the parents of the div up until `body` and `html`.

```
$(".text").parents()
[
<div class=​"menu" style=​"background-color:​ red;​ ">​…​</div>​, 
<div>​…​</div>​, 
<div>​…​</div>​, 
<body>​…​</body>​,
<html>​…​</html>​
]

parents = $(".text").parents();
var rootElement = $(parents[parents.length-3])
```

I do `-3` because I'm not including `body` and `html` (that's `-2` and the array is 0 based so subtract another). You could not do this subtraction and specify a selector like `.parents("div")` and just get the last one, too. You'll need to know what kind of element the root element is though.